# Bootpag stopped working

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

My page was working until recently. No changes have been made to it.

The `bootpag` won't load now.

When I load the page I get this error in chrome-console:

```
dashboard.php?dashboard:31 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bootpag is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://sslhost:8890/user/dashboard.php?dashboard:31:23)
    at j (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js:2:27295)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js:2:28108)
    at Function.ready (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js:2:29942)
    at HTMLDocument.J (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js:2:30308)(anonymous function) @ dashboard.php?dashboard:31j @ jquery.min.js:2fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2ready @ jquery.min.js:2J @ jquery.min.js:2
```

What should I do?

Comment: Check if you load bootpag library properly.

Comment: As i sad it was working good

Comment: It is hard to help you without your code.

Comment: The code is huge that why i have posted this.......

Comment: Are you loading bootpag from CDN?

Comment: Yes I'm loading it from cdn

Comment: Maybe it's broken link ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128477/discussion-between-mickey-and-makshh).